# Git is not working with vimdiff

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I am using *meld* with git for merging and I want to try vimdiff. Configured three way merge with git and then my own diff command:

```
[merge]
    tool = vimdiff3
    conflictstyle = diff3
[mergetool "vimdiff3"]
    cmd = gvim -f -d \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

But everytime I try to run mergetool, git just quickly respond "[file] seems unchanged" and skips the merge.

On top of that, I'd like to get real three-way merge (four files) with merged window in the bottom, this shold work but I saw many reports it is not working on the internet:

```
    cmd = gvim -f -d -c \"wincmd J\" \"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

Comment: Try [splice](https://bitbucket.org/sjl/splice.vim) for three-way merge.

Comment: Or [threesome](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/threesome.vim/) which is nothing short of _awesome_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the upcomming `mergetools/vimdiff3` setting (for git 2.0.x Q3 2014) would work for you.

See [commit 7c147b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c147b77d34f072c40b912fafba499727921fa6e) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec), merged only recently in [commit 3a9dae7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a9dae783bb66c18409d42d07949456dde8c4c62) (June 2014):

#### `mergetools`: add `vimdiff3` mode

> It's similar to the default, except that the other windows are hidden.
>   This ensures that removed/added colors are still visible on the main merge window, but the other windows not visible.
>
> Specially useful with merge.conflictstyle=diff3.

```
gvimdiff3|vimdiff3)
  if $base_present
  then
    "$merge_tool_path" -f -d -c 'hid | hid | hid' \
      "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED"
  else
    "$merge_tool_path" -f -d -c 'hid | hid' \
      "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
  fi
;;
```

The new file [`mergetools/vimdiff3`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3a9dae783bb66c18409d42d07949456dde8c4c62/mergetools/vimdiff3) has been added, which means that all you would need to do is:

```
git mergetool --tool=vimdiff3
```

(without having to configure `mergetool.vimdiff3.cmd`)